# Highlight new posts in django/react

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-queryset

I have Post model in django which has Channel as foreign key. What I want to do is , whenever there is a new post in post model, that channel should get highlighted and that should be user specific. What I am thinking is whenever new post is created, there will be one flag `is_highlighted` which will be set to true. Is this the right way to do? any other better way? TIA

```
class Post(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="post_user_id")

    channel =  models.ForeignKey(
        Channel,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="post_channel_id")
```

and channel model is

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    
    channel_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        help_text="Channel channel_name")
```

Comment: Maybe you can do it in front, if you have an array of posts, add the classname highlighted to the first item or the last of the array (depending on the order to show)

Comment: Just store their creation date, and highlight them at frontend, based if they new (for example created less then 1 hour ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution in the long term would be to store the creation date of the record which can be done by adding the line

`creation_date = models.DateField("creation_date", auto_now_add=True)` into the Post model that you would like this to apply to. If you are using a REST api to communicate between your Django backend and React frontend, you will then need to serialize this in order to have the date added to the json which the React app uses, then on your frontend code you can have a simple script that highlights the post when the difference between the current date and the creation_date is greater than a certain time period. This should fix your problem and automate the process of changing highlighting.